# word by word display animation not working in IE

Tags: jquery, animation, explorer

Does anybody know why the following code isn't working in IE? (working nice in other browsers)

```
            div.hide().contents().each(function() {
                var words;
                if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                    words = '<span> ' + this.data.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
                    $(this).replaceWith(words);
                } else if (this.nodeType === 1) {
                    this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
                }
            });

            // Remove any empty spans that were added
            div.find('span').hide().each(function() {
                if( !$.trim(this.innerHTML) ) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });

            div.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
                $(this).css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=40)');
                $(this).delay(400 * i).fadeIn(600);
            });
```

Any workaround to have the word by word display effect working in IE?

EDIT:

Created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dh3F/

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I don't get any error. The issue is that the text doesn't display at all!

Comment: Replacing fadeIn(600) with fadeTo(1, 600) might help

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make any difference

Comment: Could you please add a live example?

Comment: @Jorge There's a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dh3F/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found a way to display letter by letter in IE (working in other browsers as well), using the lettering.js library:

HTML markup:

```
<div class='intro'>
    <div class='starthidden intro'>{{ poem.introLine1 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden intro'>{{ poem.introLine2 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden intro'>{{ poem.introLine3 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden intro'>{{ poem.introLine4 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden intro'>{{ poem.introLine5 }}</div>
    <br>
</div>
<div class='verse'>
    <div class='starthidden trait'>{{ poem.traitLine1 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden trait'>{{ poem.traitLine2 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden trait'>{{ poem.traitLine3 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden trait'>{{ poem.traitLine4 }}</div>
    <div class='starthidden trait'>{{ poem.traitLine5 }}</div>
    <br>
</div>
etc
```

JQuery:

```
var div = $('.starthidden');
var delay = 400;
var fadeIn = 600;
div.lettering();
div.find('span').hide();
div.show().find('span').each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(delay * i).fadeIn(fadeIn);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line. It works in IE9 but not 8 or 7.

`this.innerHTML = '<span> ' + this.innerHTML.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';`

It's not liking `this.innerHTML`. Thankfully you are using jQuery!

use this instead:

```
$(this).html(function(index, oldhtml){
    return '<span> ' + oldhtml.split(/\s+/).join(' </span><span> ') + ' </span>';
});
```

Comment: Did you manage to have it working in IE8 or IE7? I just tried with IE8 and the text won't appear neither: jsfiddle.net/Mb8gs

Comment: I get an error: "unexpected call to method or property access", and the code "{this.nodeType === 1)&&(this.appendChild(a)}" is highlighted.